# Feed API: are their any API exist to read the feed easily

Tags: api, rss, feed, atom-feed, google-feed-api

Suppose I have 10 feed URLs.

If I want to read them, I need to make 10 requests and I need to parse every response. Sometimes the feed is not well-defined, I may get an error when my parser parses them.

Are there any APIs to read the feed by making a request to them and then give me a result through response or JSON?

That would mean making 1 request instead of 10, no need to parse the result and make less processing. Are their any APIs to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is : http://superfeedr.com/ 
We do normalize the data, deal with the polling or find the best way to get that content in realtime. Finally, we push that content to you, in the format that you want (Atom or JSON).